# using matplotlib on Mac for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Wondering if anyone have met with similar issues on Mac OSX? If so, how do you resolve? Thanks.

Here are document, code and error message,

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
=========================================================
Logistic Regression 3-class Classifier
=========================================================

Show below is a logistic-regression classifiers decision boundaries on the
`iris <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set>`_ dataset. The
datapoints are colored according to their labels.

"""
print(__doc__)


# Code source: Gaël Varoquaux
# Modified for documentation by Jaques Grobler
# License: BSD 3 clause

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
Y = iris.target

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5)

# we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
logreg.fit(X, Y)

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
Z = logreg.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 3))
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, edgecolors='k', cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
plt.xlabel('Sepal length')
plt.ylabel('Sepal width')

plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/personal/law/justech/featureExtraction/testLogisticRegression.py", line 22, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 114, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 24, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _macosx
RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other backends. If you are Working with Matplotlib in a virtual enviroment see 'Working with Matplotlib in Virtual environments' in the Matplotlib FAQ
```

Comment: "If you are Working with Matplotlib in a virtual enviroment see 'Working with Matplotlib in Virtual environments' in the Matplotlib FAQ" -- Have you done that?

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks and vote up. I am not using virtualenv, not sure if conda or miniconda is also so-called virtual environment in this context? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, no need to vote up every reply you get. You especially don't need to state that you're doing it.

Comment: I haven't used Anacoda / miniconda, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was used as a Virtualenv

Comment: Anyway, I will change to system framework, thanks for all the help @cricket_007.

Comment: @cricket_007 "no need to vote up every reply you get. You especially don't need to state that you're doing it. " Vote up and agree 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a virtual enviorment? Right now it thinks your python isn't a framework. in your terminal run

```
which python
```

and make sure it returns

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

you can always intall python as a framework at python https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Thanks Grant, vote up and here are the return for `which python` `/Users/foo/miniconda2/bin/python`, wondering how it matters if I install Python as a framework or not? I just need to use matplotlib as a library, as numpy and others.

Comment: Thanks Grant for the help, mark your reply as answer.

Comment: if you want to use the framework version run your script in the terminal as    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python  /path/to/script/