# SciPy on Windows with Python 2.7 install issues

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-7, scipy

Wondering if anyone met with similar issues and have solutions already? Using Windows 7.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install SciPy
Collecting SciPy
  Using cached scipy-0.18.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: SciPy
  Running setup.py install for SciPy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\foo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-r3jpxr\\
SciPy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().r
eplace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\foo\appda
ta\local\temp\pip-efo9to-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-m
anaged --compile:

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python2
7\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\py
thon27\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarnin
g: Specified path C:\projects\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.11.38-s
se2-64\lib is invalid.
      warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1548: UserWarni
ng:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\
\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1559: UserWarni
ng:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1562: UserWarni
ng:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\foo\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-r3jpxr\SciPy\setup.py",
 line 415, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "c:\users\foo\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-r3jpxr\SciPy\setup.py",
 line 411, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in
 setup
        config = configuration()
      File "c:\users\foo\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-r3jpxr\SciPy\setup.py",
 line 335, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 10
03, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 97
2, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 90
9, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 10
03, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 97
2, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 90
9, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\foo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-r3jpxr\\SciPy\\setup.py';exec(co
mpile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __
file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\foo\appdata\local\temp\pip-efo9to
-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed
 with error code 1 in c:\users\foo\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-r3jpxr\SciPy\
```

**Edit 1**, tried `pip install scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`, but met with strange issues,

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement 'scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but t
he file does not exist
Processing c:\python27\scripts\scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 299, in run

    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_
files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 587, in _prepare
_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 798, in unpack_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 705, in unpack_file
_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 599, in unpac
k_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 482, in unzip
_file
    zipfp = open(filename, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\scipy-0.18
.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl'
```

Comment: it looks like you are missing a few libraries that are needed before you can install scipy.  i would recommend `pip install conda` followed by `conda install scipy`

Comment: Thanks James, the issue of conda is it does not work quite well with matplotlib, see discussion here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059732/using-matplotlib-on-mac-for-python-2-7, and if you have some solutions which makes conda and matplotlib works together, appreciate for sharing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some packages, such as Scipy, require a compiler to be built using pip. Windows does not come with a compiler included, so you need to download a scipy binary file that windows can work with.

A wonderful man named Christopher Gohlke from UC Irvine has developed these binaries for windows. You can find them [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy).

Note: If you do not have Numpy installed, you cannot install SciPy. you will also need to download the Numpy Binary (also found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)). Just follow the subsequent steps to download the numpy module the same way you would download the scipy module.

Which link you install depends on whether you have a 64 bit or a 32 bit version of python, which you can check by just using the python command on your command line if you have it installed onto your PATH. Here is it visualized:

```
C:\Users\Bobby>python
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

You can find your version in the brackets. As you can see, I am running a 64 bit version of python. So I would downloaded the "scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl" file, which assumes that I am running python 2.7 (indicated byy cp27) on a 64 bit version of python (indicated by amd64).

Note: Also make sure that pip is updated. You can update it by using the following command:

```
C:\Users\Bobby\Downloads>pip install --upgrade pip
```

Once the SciPy binary downloaded, change your working directory to your downloads folder and run pip, but use the .whl file in your downloads. Here is it visualized:

```
C:\Users\Bobby>cd Downloads
C:\Users\Bobby\Downloads>pip install scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\bobby\downloads\scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-0.18.0
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, so I not only need to install `pip install scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`, but also need to install `numpy` again using the method you mentioned?

Comment: Only install pip install "scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl" if you are running a 64 bit version of python on Python 2.7. Otherwise, it will give you a nasty error. 

But yes. Install numpy using the same method if you do not already have it installed. You need numpy in order to download scipy. Otherwise, you'll also get a nasty error.

Comment: Thanks Robert, tried the command to install scipy, but met with strange issues, you can refer to edit 1 part for details, do you think it is related to numpy?

Comment: It seems like your .whl file is not in your scripts folder based on the edit. You must change your working directory to the folder where your .whl file is. I didn't touch my .whl file once I downloaded it, so I changed directories to my downloads folder. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Do I need to download this file `scipy-0.18.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` somewhere? I tried to search but cannot find it out. I thought pip may download for me but it seems I am not correct.

Comment: Hi Robert, after manual download, I can install successfully scipy, thanks for all the help and mark your reply as answer.